# Как приостановить запуск компонента

Tags: vue.js, websocket, vuex

Использую vue.js вебсокеты с помощью vue-native-websocket.
При открытии страницы отображается первый компонент Wellcome.vue, у него метод:

```
mounted() {store.dispatch('setCachmachineState','false');}
```

В файле app.js

```
Vue.use(VueNativeSock, 'ws:\\localhost:8011' {store:store, format:'json'})
```

При открытии страницы получаю ошибку что соединение с вебсокетом еще не установлено, а я уже пытаюсь заслать туда данные. 
Как правильно выстроить цепочку событий и обработку событий из вебсокета, чтобы только после подключения к серверу начал отображаться компонент Wellcome.vue? В store имеется мутация Socket_OnOpen

Comment: По `Socket_OnOpen` диспатчить об этом в стор и ставить некий ключ на что-то типа `socketsReady:true` а в зависимых компонентах на корневых элементах проверять истинность этого значения и если не тру то не рендерить

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению не вижу весь Ваш код и не могу сказать наверняка. Но вот возможные варианты:

1. Само соединение не устанавливается: ошибка с портом, урлом или ещё чем-то. Проверьте то, что соединение может быть установлено;
2. Возможно Вы не дожидаетесь завершения установки WS-соединения. В таком случае необходимо использовать async/await. Проверьте, чтобы await стоял перед вызовом установки ws-соединения.